# Why wont my collision detection or falling images work?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, rect

I have recently written this code where fruits and other things fall from the top of the screen and the frog at the bottom has to try and catch them. The collision detection is not working and neither is the falling images as they seem to just fall and get stuck at the top of the screen. This is most of my code as I cannot seem to work out which area the actual error is in:

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
######### constants ##########
jumpvel=20
fallingspeed=0.5
running= True
blue= [129,183 ,253]
pink=[255,174,201]
textcolour= [255,255,255]
x=700//2
y=1000//2

score=0

#### fruits and naughty ######
thingylist= ['fruit1.bmp','fruit2.bmp','fruit3.bmp','fruit4.bmp','fruit5.bmp','fruit1.bmp','fruit2.bmp','fruit3.bmp','fruit4.bmp','fruit5.bmp','naughty1.bmp','naughty2.bmp','naughty3.bmp',]
all_things=[]
for i in range (12):
    new_thing_image=pygame.image.load(thingylist[(random.randrange(0,12))])
    new_thing_image.set_colorkey(pink)
    new_thing_rect=new_thing_image.get_rect()
    new_thing_rect.x=random.randrange(0,950)
    new_thing_rect.y=-random.randrange(50,500)
    all_things.append([new_thing_image,new_thing_rect])


################collision###############
def checkCollision (frog_rect,all_things,score):
    collides_with=None
    for i in range (len(all_things)):
        thing_rect=all_things[i][1]
        if (frog_rect.colliderect(thing_rect)):
            score=score+100
    return collides_with



######## initialising screen#########        
pygame.init()
gamedisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600)) #making the screen
pygame.display.set_caption('frog')
clock=pygame.time.Clock()# frames per second
bg=pygame.image.load('actual clouds.bmp').convert()


############ initialising sprites##############
frog= pygame.image.load('actual frog.bmp')
frog.set_colorkey(blue)
frog_rect=frog.get_rect()
frog_rect.centerx=(x)
frog_rect.centery=(y)


####### score###########
pygame.font.init()
font= pygame.font.SysFont ('Dubai MS', 48)

##########drawing things#############
def drawThings (all_things):
    for item in all_things:
        new_thing_image, new_thing_rect= item
        gamedisplay.blit(new_thing_image, (new_thing_rect.x, new_thing_rect.y))



#########update display function###########
def update(x,y,all_things,score):
    gamedisplay.blit(bg,[0,0])
    gamedisplay.blit(frog,(x,y))
    for thing in range (len(all_things)):
        new_thing_rect=all_things[i][1]
        #thing_rect.y=thing_rect.y+fallingspeed
        new_thing_rect.y+= fallingspeed
    drawThings(all_things)
    label=font.render("score "+ str(score) ,1,textcolour)
    gamedisplay.blit(label,(750,10))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(50)



#########main game loop ############
while running == True:
    gamedisplay.blit(bg,[0,0])
    gamedisplay.blit(frog,(x,y))
    drawThings(all_things)
    label=font.render("score "+ str(score) ,1,textcolour)
    gamedisplay.blit(label,(750,10))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.event.pump()
    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()

    ########### escape ###########
    if key [pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        sys.exit()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    ########### controls ##############        
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -=2

    elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x +=2

    elif key[pygame.K_SPACE]or key[pygame.K_UP]:
        for i in range (5):
            y -= jumpvel
            update(x,y,all_things,score)
        for i in range (5):
            y += jumpvel
            update(x,y,all_things,score)
    ######## limits ####################
    if x < 10:
        x = 10
    elif (x > (900 - 2)):
        x= 900-2

    ######### falling###########

    for item in all_things:
        new_thing_image, new_thing_rect= item
        #new_thing_rect=all_things[i][1]
        #thing_rect.y=thing_rect.y+fallingspeed
        new_thing_rect.y+= fallingspeed

    ############collision detection##########
    detect=checkCollision (frog_rect, all_things,score)
    if (detect !=None):
        score=score+100

update(x,y,all_things,score)
```

The 'things' are meant to fall to the bottom of the screen for the frog to catch but they are all seemingly getting stuck at the top. When i tested the code for collision detection even when the two images collided it had no effect on the score- meaning something is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Falling images stop because of this

```
fallingspeed = 0.5
```

`rect` uses integer values to keep positon so it will rount `0.5` to integer - `int(0.5) == 0`.

When you have `y = 0` and you add `0.5` - so you could expect `y = 0.5` - it will round it to `y = 0`. In next loop you will add again `0.5` and it will round it to `y = 0` again. This way it stops on `y = 0`

When you have ie `y = -5` and you add `0.5` then you could expect `-4.5` but it round to `-4` (not `-5`) so it is moving.

Use

```
fallingspeed = 1
```

and it will not stop on `y = 0`

---

```
old_y = 0
new_y = int(old_y+0.5)
print(old_y, new_y) 

# 0 0

old_y = -5
new_y = int(old_y+0.5)
print(old_y, new_y) 

# -5 -4
```

---

Sometimes in more complex code it is important to keep position in float values and then you would have to use `float` variables instead of `rect` to keep positon and copy it to `rect` only when you have to draw or check collision

---

**collisions**

Inside `checkCollision` you set `collides_with = None` but you never change it to `True

```
 def checkCollision (frog_rect,all_things, score):
     collides_with = None

     for i in range (len(all_things)):
         thing_rect = all_things[i][1]
         if (frog_rect.colliderect(thing_rect)):
              score=score+100
              collides_with = True

     return collides_with
```

You could write it shorter

```
 def checkCollision(frog_rect,all_things, score):
     collides_with = None

     for thing_image, thing_rect in all_things:
         if frog_rect.colliderect(thing_rect):
              score = score+100
              collides_with = True

     return collides_with
```

Now it should change `score` in line

```
detect = checkCollision(frog_rect, all_things, score)
if detect:
    score = score+100
```

But if you want to change it inside `checkCollision` then you have to return value `score`. Variable `score` inside `checkCollision` is local variable and it doesn't change value in global variable `score`

```
 def checkCollision(frog_rect,all_things, score):
     collides_with = None

     for thing_image, thing_rect in all_things:
         if frog_rect.colliderect(thing_rect):
              score = score+100
              collides_with = True

     return collides_with, score
```

and then you have to assing to global `score`

```
detect, score = checkCollision(frog_rect, all_things, score)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the advice ! The falling objects are now fixed but the collision detection is working but seemingly only for some of the falling objects and not all of them as sometimes the score goes up and for some fruits it doesn't.